# How to make Sprig function kindIs interpret the string "true" as a string rather than a boolean

Tags: go-templates

The Go template Sprig function [kindIs](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/reflection.html) is used to test the type of a value:
kindIs "string" "hello" returns true.
What if the string is actually "true", not the boolean true. Is there a special character or any other mean?

(I can add a space after: "true " but it's not exactly a solution).

Comment: Could you provide example ? Function works as expected.                 
`{{ kindIs "string" true }} // false`
`{{ kindIs "string" "true" }} // true`

Comment: Actually you are correct. My mistake: I was running a Bake stage from Spinnaker with an Override Key set to false. The Bake was failing. I ran the helm template command myself (with --set mykey=true) and reproduced the error: kindIs checking for a string but detecting a boolean. In fact, the problem is in the --set: it infers the type of the value given.  I ran the same helm template command but this time used --set-string iso --set and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Should have put more background in the question: this came about when executing a Bake stage in a Spinnaker pipeline, with Key Overrides. One key (let's call it my-key) was overridden with value *true* . Bake stage failed at execution. Reproduced the error by doing a helm template command with --set my-key=true, outside spinnaker. The error had to do with kindIs checking for string but getting boolean (true). Changing to "true" didn't help.

Solution was to use helm option --set-string instead of --set.
My Spinnaker pipeline had the *Raw Overrides* checked hence the Overrides were done with --set iso --set-string.
Here's the Help pop up for Raw Overrides:

> Use --set instead of --set-string when injecting override values. Values injected using --set will be converted to primitive types by Helm.

Just had to remove the Raw Override.